# Convert hh:mm:ss to mmm:ss

Tags: java, date, timeunit

I have a Java function that convert seconds to an specific format (hh:mm:ss):

```
public static String formatChronometer(long seconds) {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
}
```

My client want to show this chronometer without the "hour" labels. Example:

1. if `100 hours => 6000:00`
2. if `0 hours and 50 minutes => 50:00`
3. if `1 hour and 12 minutes and 30 seconds => 72:30`
4. if `10 hours and 5 minutes => 600:05`
5. if `0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds => 00:00`

How should I change my method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For flexible minutes number you have to use `%d` instead of `%02d` which specify how many digit you want, your solution should look like this :

```
return String.format("%d:%02d",
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds),
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1)
);
```

---

**Example**

```
long[] times = {360000, 3000, 4350, 36300, 0};
for (long time : times) {
    String result = String.format("%d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(time),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(time) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
    System.out.println(String.format("%d : %s", time, result));
}
```

**Outputs**

```
360000 : 6000:00
3000   : 50:00
4350   : 72:30
36300  : 605:00
0      : 0:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Just ditch the hours bit.

```
return String.format("%04d:%02d",
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds),
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
```

Comment: I want a flexible minutes number (mm, mmm, mmmm and so on). I edit my question

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String formatChronometer(long seconds) {
    Duration dur = Duration.ofSeconds(seconds);
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", dur.toMinutes(), dur.toSecondsPart());
}
```

When I fed `36005` into this method, it returned `600:05`.

I take it that your chronometer seconds denote a duration, an amount of time. Either an elapsed time or a value to count down from. Not a time of day (you mentioned 100 hours an example, but the time of day is never 100 hours). In that case I would clearly use the `Duration` class for modelling it. It’s the most correct thing to do. Some use the word *self-documenting* about code written with such a consideration in mind.

The `Duration.toSecondsPart` method was only introduced in Java 9. If you are using Java 8 (or Java 6 or 7 with the ThreeTen Backport), get the seconds part by subtracting the minutes and then converting to seconds:

```
    long minutes = dur.toMinutes();
    dur = dur.minusMinutes(minutes);
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, dur.toSeconds());
```

Then the result is the same.

PS If your seconds denoted a time-of-day instead, the correct and self-documenting solution would be to use the `LocalTime` class:

```
    LocalTime chrono = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(seconds);
    return String.format("%02d:%02d",
            chrono.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY), chrono.getSecond());
```

This will reject seconds values greater than `86399` with an exception since the time of day cannot be `24:00` or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `hours` from the formatting

```
public static String formatChronometer(long seconds) {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
}
```